# Should time be a loop or a line?

Tags: spacetime, time, causality, topology, closed-timelike-curve

It's interesting to see that torus was so popular in physics, that it worked so well. There was famous Gauss–Bonnet theorem which stated basically
$$\oint_S K dS= 2\pi \chi(S)$$
where K was the curvature and $\chi(S)$ was the Euler characteristic of the surface. In the case of torus, $\chi(S)=0$. Then one consider was $\oint_S K dS= 0$ a necessity or a coincidence.

This lead to the question of what's the Euler characteristic for the spacetime? One could use a line segment for each of the space direction of characteristic 1. However, that geometry was not very satisfactory and the defining was a mess. For the purpose of "nice", one use the protective plane of characteristic 1 to represent each of the space direction. To proceed, by adding an extra space direction to the existing space direction, one identify a common point of origin by identifying a common vertices. Thus, $\chi(X_1\otimes X_2 \otimes ... \otimes X_n)=1$. The next step was to add in time.

However, here one had two choice. First, if one let time to be a circle, by identifying a common point of origin, the Euler characteristic would be $\chi(X_1\otimes X_2 \otimes ... \otimes X_n\otimes X_0)=0$, same as the torus. However, if one let time to be a line segment, $\chi(X_1\otimes X_2 \otimes ... \otimes X_n\otimes X_0)=2$(or $1$ if one were to remove one of the vertices), indicating a none zero $\oint_S K dS$.

The above explained where the question came from. However, in the context of orthodox physics, the periodic identification of time did make the convince from time to time, and yet an ordered structure was wildly assumed and accepted. Should time be a loop or a line(segment)?

Comment: *The identification was in the target space.

Comment: For the Euler characteristic of the space-time, it is given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern%E2%80%93Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem#Four-dimensional_manifolds). Whether time should be a loop of a line is related to whether you use Euclidean or Minkowskian signature.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux Thank you for pointing that out. To assume the simple geometry and to use the above argument, the Euclidean signature(the loop after the wick rotation) had characteristic $0$ with an intrinsic sense of flatness $\oint KdS=0$, where the Minkowski signature(the line segment) had characteristic of a sphere and must be curved. That make so much sense.